# how to call create webapi(blazor server app) in client side(blazor webassembly)

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I create a blazor server app project and I use a webapi built in crud api framework

EmpsController.cs

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EmpsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly sqldbcontext _context;

        public EmpsController(sqldbcontext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Emps
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Emp>>> Getemps()
        {
            return await _context.emps.ToListAsync();
        }

       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Emp>> PostEmp(Emp emp) //I want to call this webapi in clientside(webassembly app)
        {
            _context.emps.Add(emp);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEmp", new { id = emp.empid }, emp);
        }
```

and then I create a blazor webassembly project and create a razor component

Registration.razor

```
@page "/registration"
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager
<h3>Registration</h3>
@using CrudBlazorServerApp.Data

<div>
    UserName: <input type="text" id="txtusername" placeholder="Enter Your UserName" @bind="@username" required /><br />
    Address: <input type="text" id="txtempaddress" placeholder="Enter Your Address" @bind="@address" required /><br />
    Password:  <input type="text" id="txtpassword" placeholder="Enter Your Password" @bind="@password" required /><br />
    Country: <input type="text" id="txtcountry" placeholder="Enter Your Country" @bind="@country" required /><br />
    <button @onclick="Create">Submit</button><br /><br /><br /><br />
    <a href="https://localhost:44399/">Click Here For Login</a>
</div>

@code {
    string username = "";
    string address = "";
    string password = "";
    string country = "";

    Emp empList = new Emp();

    protected async Task Create()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps",empList);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        @if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var returnuserdata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var userdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(returnuserdata);
            if (userdata != null)
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
            }
            else
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/registration");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server side(blazor server app project)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6GVI.png

client side(webassembly project)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZxua.png

I am trying to create record but record not created?

what I am missing?

which place need to correction?

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't have any information about the model in the POST so I'm assuming the property names using Delphi notation. Blazor uses the new `System.Text.Json` for serialization and if not set it will try to parse the data in case sensitive form. (The `PostAsJsonAsync<T>` also uses the new api in the background)
This could be one possible source of the issue.

To fix this you can pass a settings to the serializer. For example:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
};
var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(empDetails, serializeOptions);
```

From the information provided this is the only issue I could think of. You could also try to add input validation like `FluentValidator`.

Comment: not solve the issue stil I am trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should not create the `HttpClient` in that way, you need to inject in the same way the *FetchData* sample does in the basic sample app
https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/7c5e80ebf7f238505f1281f550666600

Try addding

```cs
@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient client;
```

at the top of your page. Change your `Create` method as follows:

```cs
protected async Task Create()
  {
      HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync<Emp>("https://localhost:44333/api/emps",empList);
      @if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          var userdata = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<YourExpectedResult>();
            if (userdata != null)
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
            }
            else
            {
                navigationManager.NavigateTo("/registration");
            }
        }
    }
```

I've used `YourExpectedResult` as the type you expect as your sample does not say what type you're deserializing to.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1